# Allow user to take Picture in portrait view dimensions in UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

My applications is in portrait view only.

I am taking an image from camera and showing it to image view from `UIImagePickerController`.
Now if I rotate the device then it takes the picture in landscape view and image dimensions change from `1936*2592`(that is for portrait) to `2592*1936`.

Now I want to display the same image in my portrait view exactly like the default camera do.

Please tell me how can I do that?
or is it possible to lock `UIImagePicker` to portrait only?

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your image

```
- (UIImage *)imageByScalingToSize:(CGSize)targetSize
{

    UIImage *sourceImage = yourImage;
    UIImage *newImage = nil;

    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    //   CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    // this is actually the interesting part:

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil) NSLog(@"could not scale image");


    return newImage ;
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the suggestion but I have already tried this method, If width>height then it will fix the image according to that and I will get width more than height according to aspect ratio and I will be left with blank space in UIImageView